# Equivalent to ASP.NET Web.Config

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm new to Windows Phone 8 development. I'm coming from an ASP.NET Web Forms background where settings are stored in Web.Config. As some of you know, the Web.Config settings are hierarchical in nature where values are overridden depending on their location (root Web.config, machine.config, app level Web.config)

I am creating an app that calls into a third party API. The third party API uses OAuth which requires personal key information. I plan on open sourcing the code so I don't want to expose those keys.

If this was ASP.NET, I'd store the keys in a Web.config file outside of the app. This way, I'd be safe to publish my app to the public.

How would I achieve the same with a Windows Phone 8 app?

Answer (score 3):

`App.config` functionality does not exist in Silverlight and WP apps. You can use `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` to save/receive settings.

If you still want to use something similar to `App.config` then you can check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/07/06/app-config-for-wp7-applications.aspx) for a similar functionality implementation.

Comment: IsolatedStorageSettings works great for storing application settings but does not solve my problem of protecting private keys when publishing to a public repository. I solved my problem using the method described on this page: http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2012/1/26/windows-phone-app-config-settings-thinking-outside-the-box.html