# Windows Phone 8 System.Configuration

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, window, app-config, system.configuration

I am developing a windows Phone application with Multiple projects in it. But, I am facing problem to have App.config file and get the details from this config file to all the projects

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794494/equivalent-to-asp-net-web-config/16799896#16799896